# VS Code - Find & Replace - replace all div's with h2's while keeping the inner content

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have almost 200+ files of almost thousands of lines of code like this.

```
<div class="bg-gray-100 w-full p-2 text-bold">Content</div>
```

I need to replace these div's, all with the same class, with h2's, while keeping the inner content. How could I use Replace in Files to do this? I could find all instances of `<div class="bg-gray-100 w-full p-2 text-bold">` and replace them with `<h2 class="bg-gray-100 w-full p-2 text-bold">`, but then I'd still be stuck with the `</div>` closing tags that I'd need to change to closing h2's throughout the entire codebase. No fun.

I tried a regex: `<div class="bg-gray-100 w-full p-2 text-bold">[\s\S]+</div>`, but it replaced the inner content with the actual text of the regex.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you would always be searching for `<div>` tags which also have the closing element, you may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    <div\s+([^>]+)>(.*?)</div>
Replace: <h2 $1>$2</h2>
```

### Demo

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Adam this will give a problem if you have a `<div>xx<div>xx</div>xx</div>` construct with or without tag arguments

Comment: @rioV8 This, and many other edge cases.  For a fool-proof approach, something like xpath should be used, not regex.  I only answered the exact question which was asked.